# How to import and process Excel file in fastest way?

Tags: sql, .net

We want to import and process the Excel data into SQL using ASP.Net

For now we identified OLEDB is the best approach to read the excel file as most of our data are in Tabular format.

Next to save this data into SQL, we have to process it to convert all the raw data to equivalent IDs. for example i have a below table

```
Country State       Sales 
USA     Illinios    43435 
USA     Wisconsin   3435 
India   Karnataka   3434 
India   Kerala      34345
```

Should be saved as

```
CountryID  StateID  Sales 
22         122      43435 
22         123      3435 
26         201      3434 
26         202      34345
```

Please suggest the best and fastest way to do this

Comment: which `c#` or `vb` and any code you tried ?

Comment: I use EPPLus for reading and creating excel files [link](https://epplus.codeplex.com). If you were using this you could open your excel file and read the data into a datatable and use bulk insert to put into into SQL server

Comment: There is never best or fastest way. I would import all textual data into temporary table and insert corresponding IDs into real table using SQL procedure. Sure you must implement some checks to deal with invalid data, like having State = "Illinosi" or similar errors.

Answer (score 0):

1. Create a Data dictionary containing stateID and State
2. Create a Data dictionary containing CountryId and Country
3. As you read the rows from the spreadsheet lookup the stated and CountyID and add the rows to a datatable
4. Use bulk insert to insert the data into SQL table

Comment: here, i am planning to read data from excel through OLEDB so the raw data will come directly to datatables. Will it not a performance hit to compare against data dictionary each field and insert to another datatable?

Comment: Data Dictionaries are designed for fast lookup. The alternative is to bulk insert the raw data and use an sql SP to convert it